# eBay Trading API GetCategories request returns 'Application name invalid'

Tags: php, ebay-api, trading

When I tried to retreive all categories through the eBay Trading API with the method `getCategories`, I got this error:

> FailureApplication name invalid.API application "222277"
>   invalid.127Error222277RequestError895E895_INTL_APICATALOG_17257399_R1

The header used is:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:text/xml',
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 895',
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetCategories',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0'
);
```

The XML postfields:

```
$body = <<<BODY
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetCategoriesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>auth token......</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <CategorySiteID>0</CategorySiteID>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
</GetCategoriesRequest>
BODY;
```

and curl code:

```
$connection = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
        curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($connection);
        curl_close($connection);
```

Comment: Please note, that you're using a old API version (895) current version is 1067. See [release notes](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/ReleaseNotes.html). This might not be the reason of your error. I think your problem is coming from a wrong header value for `X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME`. See [Error codes](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/Errors/ErrorMessages.htm) and search for "Application name invalid" / Code 127.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ebay** provides an API test tool.

It will pre-populate your credentials and let you make a test call.

[Test Tool](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/default.aspx)

This will help you debug any errors that you might get.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, eBay recently discontinued their API test tool. However, there are some 3rd party ones that may suffice.

For your issue, I recommend using the simpler Shopping API call called [GetCategoryInfo](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetCategoryInfo.html). You don't need to POST your request or send any HTTP headers, and you can build your entire call into 1 URL/REST/GET request. This makes debugging much easier.

Either way you go about it, I don't think you can retrieve all of eBay's categories with 1 request. Instead, plan to loop through the category tree at each level, collecting the child category names and IDs.